# Considering sample size as controlling factor in meta-regression

Tags: regression, self-study, meta-analysis, predictor, meta-regression

In a meta-regression, authors have 3 explanatory variables of interest for 2 countries. But all these three variables were not present in all those studies which were finally selected for meta-analysis. For example, variable 1 were present in 7 studies for country A and in 2 studies for country B. Therefore, the authors also considered country and sample size in the regression equation along with the interested explanatory variable and said "we conducted separate meta-regression for each covariate controlling for country and sample size".

I have attached the layout of their one piece of output:

[image]

Is it a valid analysis to consider country and sample size as controlling factors in the regression for interpreting whether the variable of interest (for example, Sex) is significant?

Comment: Considering country is acceptable, but sample size risks creating an inaccurate/unstable model, as sample size is directly or indirectly impacting on analytical weights used for meta-regression. Thus, I would at least recommend the authors to run a sensitivity analysis excluding sample size from the model.